# how to connect 2 webapps in 2 nodeport service?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a single node k8s cluster with 2 web applications running on 2 NGINX k8s pods.

nginx-deployment1 --> WEBAPP1 --> nginx-svc-app1 --> <K8s_controler_IP>:30080/webapp1

nginx-deployment2 --> WEBAPP2 --> nginx-svc-app2 --> <K8s_controler_IP>:30081/webapp2

Its connecting only to the respective nodeport ip but not connecting to <K8s_controler_IP>:30080/webapp1 and <K8s_controler_IP>:30081/webapp2. Could you please help me understand what am i missing?

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment1
  labels:
    name: nginx-app1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nginx-app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx-app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc-app1
  labels:
    name: nginx-svc-app1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      name: app1_port
  selector:
    name: nginx-app1
    
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment2
  labels:
    name: nginx-app2
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nginx-app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx-app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc-app2
  labels:
    name: nginx-svc-app2
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30081
      name: http
  selector:
    name: nginx-app2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port configurations are incorrect. You need to set `targetPort: 80` for both services. When you use the `NodePort` service type and specify the `NodePort`, the `port` field is irrelevant. That is the port that typically receives the incoming traffic for the service endpoint. So, specifying both would mean:

1. Receive incoming traffic on an endpoint with port 80.
2. Receive incoming traffic to Node port 30080.

And you are not specifying a `targetPort` which is the port that receives the traffic in the pods of the deployment. So, the traffic is coming in, but not being forwarded anywhere.

You need to add `targetPort: 80` to both services and remove the `port` parameter.

Additionally, you're not running 2 pods, but you are running 2 deployments, each with 3 pods (replicas) in them. And the traffic you will send to each service, will be 'distributed' by the service, on all the pods that will match the selector - i.e. all 3 of your pods. It's important to understand how the communication takes place.

Also, `k8s_controller_ip` is an incorrect way of describing the IP address. You should use the term `k8s Node IP` or `k8s_master_node_ip`. The IP address belongs to the node that is running the cluster, not to any controller.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
when i remove the port, it throws the below error,

**error: error validating "svc-web1-node-port.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.ports[0]): missing required field "port" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false**

Comment: You have to add the `targetPort` parameter as well, in place of `port`.